# How Foundry knows if the build is already done or not?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, foundry

As we all know foundry skips the compilation for an already-built project. How does Foundry check whether the project has any changes, whether to build or skip the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It saves a hash of the contents of each file, so if any of them has changed it will be recompiled.